# Can't run django rest framework with docker

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, dockerfile

I'm currently learning Docker and django rest at the same time.
When i run the command **python3 manage.py runserver** I can access to django admin page from http://localhost:8000/admin/, but when i run  **docker run -p 80:80 docker_django_tutorial** the page is anccesible. (docker_django_tutorial is the name of my docker image)
I guess i need to add somewhere python3 manage.py runserver in my dockerfile ?

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
#Use the Python3.7.2 container image
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and here my file **requirements.txt**:

```
Django==3.1.1
djangorestframework
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling Django to listen on port 8000 but then telling Docker to expose port 80. Use `-p 8000:8000` instead. If you want it to listen on port 80, you can use `-p 80:8000`. The first number is host (your system) port and the second is container port (Django).

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know why I keep making stupids errors T^T